# read -a doesn't work in unix

Tags: arrays, shell, unix

I'm trying to split a paramameter into array so that i can then assign into different variables, but somehow i get error saying 'read -a' doesn't work.

command:

```
bash-4.1$ ./sftpupstream.ksh CheckFile "aaa|bbbb|ccc|dddd"
aaa|bbbb|ccc|dddd
./sftpupstream.ksh[20]: read: -a: unknown option
Usage: read [-ACprsSv] [-d delim] [-u fd] [-t timeout] [-n count] [-N count] [var?prompt] [var ...]
```

Code:

```
RUN_MODE=$1
PARAMSTR=$2

echo $PARAMSTR
IFS="|" read -a arr <<< "$PARAMSTR"
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
        echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: What's your shell? There's no shebang here. Start your script with `#!/usr/bin/env bash` if you want to be certain that it runs in bash

Comment: (and, err... `.ksh`?) I don't see a ksh shebang either, and since there are many *many* different incompatible versions of ksh, you really need to be describing which specific one you're using.

Comment: yeah i do have it. Sorry didnt copy the whole script 
 #!/bin/ksh

Comment: Please ensure you're providing a [mcve] -- the shortest possible code that generates the same problem. (Which is to say, copying the whole script isn't ideal, but what you *do* copy should be tested to showcase the problem).

Comment: BTW, taking a closer look at that `read` command, it very much looks like a ksh one instead of a bash one. In ksh, the argument for an array is `-A`, not `-a`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy okay thank you very much for the additional information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read -a` is not a standardized option to the `read` builtin. See the POSIX standard for `read` at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html, and note that POSIX sh (the baseline specification for all POSIX shells) doesn't even specify arrays *at all*.

Rather, it's an extension, only available in specific shells. To get the extension, you must be using one of those specific shells. You can do that by:

- Explicitly starting your script with an extended shell (`bash yourscript`).
- Using a shebang indicating an extended shell (`#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as the first line of your script)

If your shell is `ksh`, the equivalent extension is `read -A`.

Comment: thank you! after i changed my shebang to be bash (it was ksh), it works now

bash-4.1$ ./sftpupstream.ksh CheckFile "aaa|bbbb|ccc|dddd"
aaa|bbbb|ccc|dddd
aaa
bbbb
ccc
dddd
bash-4.1$